# How to fix "vagrant up" error "uninitialized constant VagrantPlugins::HostDarwin::Cap::Version"

Tags: vagrant

When doing `vagrant up` I get this error:

```
==> default: Exporting NFS shared folders...
Traceback (most recent call last):
    106: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    105: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:201:in `action'
.....

/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/plugins/hosts/darwin/cap/path.rb:20:in `resolve_host_path': uninitialized constant VagrantPlugins::HostDarwin::Cap::Version (NameError)
```

I updated Vagrant and VirtualBox. How can I fix this?

Comment: Solved it on my own: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12583

Answer (score 11):

The solution is to run this command:

```
sudo curl -o /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/plugins/hosts/darwin/cap/path.rb https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hashicorp/vagrant/42db2569e32a69e604634462b633bb14ca20709a/plugins/hosts/darwin/cap/path.rb
```

This [command was found here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12583#issuecomment-975070111).

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same error:

```
uninitialized constant VagrantPlugins::HostDarwin::Cap::Version (NameError)
```

Downgrading Vagrant from `2.2.19` to `2.2.18` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed vagrant 2.2.19 with this patch contributed to https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12583:

```
+ $ diff -u /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/plugins/hosts/darwin/cap/path.rb.backup-20220104 path.rb
--- /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/plugins/hosts/darwin/cap/path.rb.backup-20220104  2022-01-04 12:35:09.000000000 +0100
+++ path.rb 2022-01-04 12:35:21.000000000 +0100
@@ -17,7 +17,8 @@
     def self.resolve_host_path(env, path)
       path = File.expand_path(path)
       # Only expand firmlink paths on Catalina
-          return path if !CATALINA_CONSTRAINT.satisfied_by?(Cap::Version.version(env))
+          host_version = env.host.capability(:version)
+          return path if !CATALINA_CONSTRAINT.satisfied_by?(host_version)

       firmlink = firmlink_map.detect do |mount_path, data_path|
         path.start_with?(mount_path)
```